# why select{ } vs select {case} cause different scheduling

Tags: go

### 1.select {case}

```
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)

    go func() {
        fmt.Println("a")
    }()
    go func() {
        fmt.Println("b")
    }()
    go func() {
        fmt.Println("c")
    }()

    fmt.Println("d")

    select {
    case _ = <-time.After(time.Second):
    }
}
```

`result:dabc`

### 2.select {}

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"

)
func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)

    go func() {
        fmt.Printf("a")

    }()

    go func() {
        fmt.Printf("b")

    }()

    go func() {
        fmt.Printf("c")

    }()

    fmt.Printf("d")
    select {}

}
```

`result:dcab`

Because I set "runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)", there's only one "Processor" in my program.

One "Processor"  has only one "runq", and in/out operation  is "FIFO"

My question is "why  always... not rand...."

Comment: same as "https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-dev/i36ieSCuSII"

Comment: Goroutine order and scheduling is non-deterministic without explicit synchronization. Don't waste your energy trying to find reason / logic about anything that is not specified / guaranteed. If you need a specific order, take care about that by using explicit synchronization.

Comment: "Pursue details" is very popular in our country ,  especially in interviews.

Comment: "Details" of something specified is entirely different than "details" of something unspecified / non-deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out.

Processor.runq is FIFO, there's another variable(runnext) here, runnext saves the lastest goroutine which where will be processed next.

The latest goroutine kicks *p*.runnext

Timer  creates a goroutine ,and this goroutine kicks *p*.runnext.

---

Processor的runnext 被定时器创建的goroutine kick调, 导致下一个执行的是定时器的goroutine,然后其他的FIFO